# change letters to cap and keep one variable if it has multiple words in it

Tags: variables, capitalization

I have a batch file that converts the variable to all uppercase letters... the problem is that if the variable has a space in it then the output is split up. how can i convert a variable (foldername) to all uppercase if there are spaces in it?

```
@REM  This makes everything uppercase.
@ SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

@ SET _SAMPLE="%foldername%"

@ CALL :UCase _SAMPLE _RESULTS
@ ECHO.%_RESULTS%

@ CALL :LCase _SAMPLE _RESULTS
@ ECHO.%_RESULTS%

@ ENDLOCAL
@ GOTO:EOF


@ :LCase
@ :UCase
@ :: Converts to upper/lower case variable contents
@ :: Syntax: CALL :UCase _VAR1 _VAR2
@ :: Syntax: CALL :LCase _VAR1 _VAR2
@ :: _VAR1 = Variable NAME whose VALUE is to be converted to upper/lower case
@ :: _VAR2 = NAME of variable to hold the converted value
@ :: Note: Use variable NAMES in the CALL, not values (pass "by reference")

@ SET _UCase=A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
@ SET _LCase=a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
@ SET _Lib_UCase_Tmp=!%1!
@ IF /I "%0"==":UCase" SET _Abet=%_UCase%
@ IF /I "%0"==":LCase" SET _Abet=%_LCase%
@ FOR %%Z IN (%_Abet%) DO SET _Lib_UCase_Tmp=!_Lib_UCase_Tmp:%%Z=%%Z!
@ SET %2=%_Lib_UCase_Tmp%
@REM GOTO:EOF
@REM
```

when i use this code to try and create folders it gives me as many folders as there are words in the variable i.e.:
           top= folder="TOP"
           Hill Top= folder="HILL" and folder="TOP"

any ideas from anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it pretty simple...  just use double quotes around the variable when you create the directory

%foldername%= hello world

single quotes:
mkdir "%foldername%"     makes a folder "hello" and a folder "world"

double quotes:
mkdir ""%foldername%""    makes a folder "hello world"

I felt pretty dumb when i realized this simple mistake.